# Android NDK - sigsegv invalid address (fault address: 0x10)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, segmentation-fault, android-library

I have an application that call C++ library and it works fine. I need now to convert this app to an android library. After conversion, Calling `System.loadLibrary("native-lib");` causes application crashing with this error `SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x10))`

I converted it to a library by change plugin to'com.android.library'

Should I create an android library from scratch ?

Comment: That looks like the code is accessing a null-pointer, with an offset of 16 bytes.

Comment: Ok thanks , Do you think that changing to an android library may affect something as it is already working as an application?

Comment: I don't know enough about Android development to say anything more specific.

Comment: This is tagged C++ but the error you get is from a python file. What are you using to port Python to Android? Maybe there is a problem there